# Differences between reliability and availability using an example

Tags: operating-systems

My definitions of reliability and availability are as below respectively .

reliability := property of failure interval .

availability := property of occupancy rate .

I want to show the differences between reliability and availability using some example but currently I've been failing to come up with it .

I came up with the below sentence .

The system which breaks in average per hour and the system cannot be used as break occurs for 0.1 hours .

Can this expression be used to show the differences between the 2 terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a airfield on the front line, the General is woried by the reliability of its fighter aircrafts, and hence the reliability is high , the availability is due to be high,
.
On the other hand  if the general has at its disposition a vast number of low reliable aircraft, in the echonomics of the operations, the necesary number of aircraft required for missions, may be available.

You can take this concept and create your own scenarious involving the General and its aircraft fighters, and see if and when reliability and/or availability is a cost worth taking.